# Ionic Framework - StaticInjectorError

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have this error :

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[Tab1Page -> EventProvider]: **
** StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[Tab1Page -> EventProvider]: **
** NullInjectorError: No provider for EventProvider!
Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[Tab1Page -> EventProvider]: **
** StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[Tab1Page -> EventProvider]: **
** NullInjectorError: No provider for EventProvider!

This is my code in tab1

```
this.event.loadEventsByUser(2)
.then((res:Event)=>
{
this.EventsLoad = res;
})
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

And this is my code in EventProvider.ts :

```
loadEventsByUser(userid) {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
console.log("this.userid = " + this.UserId);
this.http.api().get(‘Events/GetEventsByUserId’, { search: { userid: userid } })
.subscribe((data: any) => {
console.log("Data = " + data)
resolve(data);
})
});
```

}

And this is my code in httpclient.ts

```
get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {

return from(this.setHeaders(options)).pipe(mergeMap(options => super.post(url, options)));

}
```

Can anyone help me ? Where am’I Wrong ?

Tks for your help

Comment: You have to import your service in the providers array of app.module.ts

Answer (score 1):

You have to import **EventProvider** in the providers array of your **app.module.ts**

Something like below,

**app.module.ts**

```
import { EventProvider } from 'mention your file path here';


@NgModule({
declarations:[]
.
.
.
providers: [
EventProvider
]
})

export class AppModule { }
```